# ASP.NET Universal Providers

Tags: asp.net, membership-provider

Can somebody give some info about as to what are asp.net Universal Providers, why and when are they used?

Answer (score 1):

Basically these providers are sql agnostic and make sure your app works on sqlazure and any other sql databases